# Confusion with re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I have the string `aa{{{a {{ {aaa{` that I would like to translate to `aa { { {a { { {aaa {`. Basically every `{` must a space character before it.

My regular expression substitution function I am currently using is: `re.sub(r'[^\ ]{', lambda x:x.group(0)[0]+' {', test_case)`
The result from the function is: `aa {{ {a { { {aaa {` (Close, but there is a `{{` in the string)

My method performs very well on section like `a{a{a`. However if two `{` characters are together like `a{{a` it only seems to operate on the first `{` and completely neglect the following `{`.

A more clear example will be a large series of `{{{{{{{{{{{{`. My regex substitution returns:`{ {{ {{ {{ {{ {{ {`. Which clearly skips over every other character given tightly nested `{`.

Why are they skipping? Any help to untangle this confusion would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I am sorry to everyone out there that have the strong desire to close all the opened curly-brace.

Comment: What about just replacing each '{' for '{ ', without regex? Do you really need to use regex to achieve what you want? Also +1 for apologizing for all the unclosed curly braces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a negative lookbehind:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\s)(\{)',r' \1','{{{{{{')
```

Basically we parse the string until we hit a `{`.  If the character before it isn't whitespace (that's the `(?<!\s)` bit), the `{` matches and we replace it with a space in front.

Answer (score 2):

They are skipping because your regular expression is consuming two characters: `[^\ ]` and `{`. You need to use 0-width negative lookbehind for the preceding space in order not to consume it: `(?!<\s){`. Then you can just replace it with `" {"`, without the lambda hassle.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will do the trick:

```
re.sub (' *{', ' {', test_case)
```